# How to make ProGuard keep entire (whole) classes (with fields and methods) without using "-keep"

Tags: java, android, scala, proguard, sbt-android-plugin

If I have a Scala Android project and I use these methods in my apk...

```
scala.collection.immutable.List#::
scala.collection.immutable.List#:::
```

..., after I use ProGuard on it, it will keep `scala.collection.immutable.List` class with only 2 methods, `::` and `:::`.

Is there an option in ProGuard to keep **ALL**  methods and fields inside a class, even though they aren't currently used, but without sending ProGuard this: `-keep class scala.collection.immutable.List {*;}`

Comment: Can't you do something like `-keep class scala.** {*;}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the only way for me to do that is to determine which classes and methods are being used in my compiled classes.

I mapped them via `Map[String, Set[String]]` data structure, where the key is the class name and the corresponding `Set` value contains all the methods used from that class.

After that, it's just a matter of creating lots of `-keep` argumetns:

```
def getProGuardKeepArgs(allDeps: MMap[String, MSet[String]]): String = {
    var sb = new StringBuilder()
    for ((clazz, methods) <- allDeps) {
        sb.append("-keep class " + clazz + " {\n")

        for (method <- methods) {
            sb.append(" *** " + method + "(...);\n")
        }

        sb.append("}\n\n")
    }

    sb.toString
}
```